# Proving the existence of inverse of a polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I want to know if the following function, defined in $[0,1]$, has inverse for any $a,c\in[0,1]$.

$$x(t) := 3at(1 - t)^2 + 3ct^2(1 - t) + t^3.$$

My guess is that it has, so I'm trying to prove that its derivative is positive in $(0,1)$. So I reduce the problem to prove that

$$x'(t)=(3-9c+9a)t^2+(6c-12a)t+3a\geq0, \quad \forall a,c,t\in (0,1).$$

Here the corner cases $a,c,t \in \{0,1\}$ are no problem, so I won't pay much attention on where the equality is reach. If I assume $x'(t)\leq 0$, I get some conditions over $a$ and $c$ which are the following:

$$a\leq c \leq a +\frac{1}{3},$$
$$c\leq 2a.$$

Obtaining these inequalities are not a big deal, I get them from looking at the coefficients of the polynomial $x'(t)$ and doing easy calculations. Using these inequalities I'm trying to get to a contradiction so that there is no $a,b,c\in (0,1)$ where $x'(t)<0$ and these inequalities are true. However, it's been more complicated than what I thought at the begining.

Can anyone help me to prove that the function always has inverse or give me a counterexample where it hasn't?

Comment: I haven't checked your calculations but for a=2/12 and c=3/12 you can get a<c<a+1/3 and c<2a, so getting a contradiction from these is  impossible

Comment: The contradiction doesn't come from inequalities themselves. The thing is that when those two inequalities are true (which can be as you have pointed out), I wan't to prove that it's not possible that $x'(t)<0$ for a certain $t\in(0,1)$. Thanks for the answer, I edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: In the derivative I get (-12a+6c)t, could you check it?

Comment: You are right, thanks again.

Comment: Does it change what you need to show or was it just a typo?

Comment: It was just a typo, I have edited the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already shown that if $c < a$ the derivative is positive. Now take the derivative not by expanding the polynomial and deriving, but seeing it as a sum of products (do not expand $1-t$ terms)

$ ( 3at(1-t)^2 )' = (3at)'(1-t)^2 + 3at( (1-t)^2 )' = 3a(1-t)^2  -6at(1-t) \dots $

In this form it is clear that when $ c \ge a $  then $ x'(t) \ge 0 $.